# Паттерн Repository и принцип единой отвественности

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, laravel, repository

Всем привет!

При использовании паттерна у меня возникают трудности:

**1**. В случае связанных данных. 
Например, у нас есть сайт с объявлениями о продаже авто. На главной странице нужно вывести их список с пагинацией и фильтрами по свойствам:

```
SELECT (список полей)
FROM Posts
   LEFT JOIN Cars on Cars.id = Posts.carId
   LEFT JOIN Cities on Cities.id = Posts.cityId  
   LEFT JOIN Regions on Regions.id = Cities.regionId 
   LEFT JOIN Countries on Countries.id = Regions.countryId
   LEFT JOIN Models on Models.id = Cars.modelId
   LEFT JOIN Brands on Brands.id = Models.brandId
WHERE Cars.condition = 'new' AND Regions.id = 1 AND Models.id = 2 
LIMIT 10, 10
```

С точки зрения принципа "единой ответственности", в данном случае, нужно под каждую сущность/таблицу создать отдельные репозитори: BrandRepository, CountryRepository и т.д.

Но как тогда собрать такой запрос используя группу репозиториев, не нарушая принципа единой ответственности?

**2.**  При создании объявления нужно произвести запись в 2 таблицы: Posts и Cars. Как в сервисе использовать транзакции между репозитариями ?

Comment: как вы понимаете смысл принципа единой ответственности?

Comment: Каждый объект имеет одну обязанность.

Comment: суть принципа - у каждого класса должна быть одна причина для изменений. будь у вас C# - у вас был бы шаблонный класс-репозиторий (у которого обязанность - это делать вид что таблица в базе - это массив объектов - суть паттерна репозитория). и класс-контекст, в котором были бы объявлены конкретные репозитории. у первого причина изменения - схема механизма отображения базы на таблицу, у второго - смена набора таблиц. как это выглядит в php под конкретный фреймворк - я не уверен.

Comment: а ответ на 2 - это паттерн unit of work. сорри, опять же, реализация зависит от конкретного фремворка, но почти все они как-то этот паттерн релизуют в более-менее готовом виде.

Comment: unit of work - в laravel нет unit of work, там классический active records.  Да ,на с# много реализаций и статей, но тяжело их понять не зная языка самого.)

Comment: под C# есть пару мейнстримных реализаций в виде готовых ORM, и еще пару "реализаций" которые просто разделяют готовые orm (т.е. готовую реализацию orm+unit of work+repository) на отдельные интерфейсы. с нуля там такое никто не пишет, и прямых аналогов на php не найдете (потому что у вас сахара в виде LINQ и лямбд нет). Ждите специалистов по PHP :(

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. UnitOfWork есть вроде на php только у Symfony 2. Но мне как-то сама эта ORM не нравится, хотелось более легковесного решения.

Answer (score 2):

Я прошу извинить меня за то что отвечаю на вопрос годичной давности. Но ответа нет, и может быть кому-нибудь пригодится мой.

Вы сами говорите, что у вас есть объявления и вам нужно выбрать несколько для главной страницы. Значит вам необходим репозиторий Объявлений. Объекты типа Объявления будут содержать всю необходимую для отображения на странице информацию, репозиторий Объявлений будет возвращать вам именно такие объекты, например, предоставляя метод `select($filters = [], $fromId = 0, $limit = 100)`. Внутри этого метода и будет ваш запрос с join'ами.

При создании объявления вы будете инстанцировать объект Объявление и сохранять его в репозитории Объявлений вызывая метод `save(Post $post)`. Внутри этого метода будет транзакция и запись в соответсвующие таблицы.

Как видите, получается что вы работаете с репозиторием как с коллекцией объектов Объявление, и вся ответственность по отображению Объявлений на базу данных находится единственно в нём.

Так как объекты типа Марка(Brand), Город(City) и другие, скорее всего, тоже нужны в вашем приложении, для них потребуются отдельные Репозитории. Тогда инстанцирование этих объектов из результатов SQL-запроса можно делегировать соответствующим репозиториям, например реализовав в них метод `map($row, $prefix = '')`. Сохранять отдельные сущности можно вне транзакции (раз это отдельные сущности, то нет несогласованности данных, если марка добавилась, а объявление нет).

Вот как я это себе представляю:

```
class Post {

    public function __construct($id, $title, Brand $brand) {
        // ...
    }

}

class Brand {

    // ...

}

class PostReposiroty {

    private $db;

    private $brandRepository;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
        // зависимость не обяхательно хардкодить, просто для примера
        $this->brandRepository = new BrandRepository($this->db);
    }

    public function select($filters = [], $fromId = 0, $limit = 100) {
        // $rows = $this->db->query('sql-запрос с join'ами');
        $rows = [[
            'id' = 1,
            'title' => 'Foo bar',
            'barnd_id' => 1,
            'brand_name' => 'baz'
        ]];

        return array_map([$this, 'map'], $rows);
    }

    public function map($row, $prefix = '') {
        return new Post(
            $row['id'],
            $row['title'],
            $this->brandRepository->map($row, 'brand');
        );
    }

    public function save(Post $post) {
        $ok = $this->brandRepository->save($post->getBrand());
        if ( ! $ok) {
            throw new Exception('Не удалось сохранить марку');
        }

        // $result = $this->db->insert или update
        $result = true;

        return $result;
    }
}

class BrandRepository {

    // аналогично PostReposiroty

}
```

При необходимости можно реализовать и транзацкии, например определив класс Транзакции и передавая его между вызовами `save`. Ну и вообще, внутри и снаружи этих классов можно написать много интересного кода, при этом не нарушая ответственность репозиториев за доступ к объектами приложения.